# Entity Framework is not refreshing the list of stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm modifying an existing project in Visual Studio 2012 and using Entity Framework 4.0.

I created a new stored procedure in SQL Server 2008. I wanted to add this stored procedure to the Entity Framework model (`.edmx` file) but without success.

I cannot see the stored procedure in the drop down list and the drop down list is not refreshing (Right click -> Add new Function Import) even though I had granted execute permissions to dbo.

Reboot my computer and VS does not help me also.

Comment: have you tried *Update model from database* by right clicking on the designer surface and select that. Then a dialog would appear for you to select the stored procedures to be imported.

Comment: Yes i did but without success!